# Not able to run django-celery on window 7

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I m able to run celery with django on linux but not on windows 7.

```
>python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
Unknown command: 'celery'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Inside `settings.py`, `'djcelery'` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. And djcelery bootstrap code is added in `settings.py`.

How to debug this error?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py help`?

Comment: hi mariodev, error was due to corrupt installation. I did celery installation again. It is working fine now.